# Unrecognized symbol '<' in Riemann

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, riemann

```
(tcp-server {:host "127.0.0.1" :port 5555})

(let [userindex1 (default :ttl 300 (update-index (index)))])  
  (let [email (mailer {....email configuration})]
            (streams
        (where (service "log")
            (smap
              (fn [events]
               (let [count-of-transaction (count (filter #(= "error" (:type %)) events))]
                  (event
                  {
                     :status "Failure"
                     :metric  count-of-failures 
                     :total-fail (< count-of-failures 2)})))

              (where (and (= (:status event) "Failure")
                          (:total-fail event))


                (email "xxx@xx.com")
                 )prn))))
```

When I use `>` symbol  `:total-fail (> count-of-failures 2)` but when I use less than symbol `<` I am getting `unrecognized symbol <` error. How to use less than symbol.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you add your require/use/import statements?

Comment: you can also try `clojure.core/<` here to see, if something is messing things up big time

Comment: @murphy. I didnt use any require/use/import statements in my code. Do you need to add it. If so please help me what reference should be added to resolve this issue.